# Vertical alignment on mobile devices and randomised colour javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to make some tweaks to this website and having a bit of trouble.

http://accoutrements.studio

The 'Accoutrements' logo should be horizontally and vertically centred in the page. This seems to work fine on a desktop device, but it mis-aligns on a mobile device. See the screenshot for a better example — https://i.stack.imgur.com/87qiM.png

There's also a script to randomise the colour every time you click on the logo. However I'd like to have it so the page loads in black and white and then only randomises on click. At the moment I've created two separate pages (/index and /colour), but is there anyway to edit the javascipt so I don't have two separate pages?

There also seems to be a black box when you hover over the logo at smaller screen sizes. I'm not too sure why this is — https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6kK1.png

Sorry for all of the questions and thank you!

**Index**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180">
    <link href="/favicon-32x32.png" rel="icon" sizes="32x32" type="image/png">
    <link href="/favicon-16x16.png" rel="icon" sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
    <link href="/manifest.json" rel="manifest">
    <meta content="#ffffff" name="theme-color">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="Accoutrements is a design studio established in 2016 by Jacob D'Rozario and Joseph Ng." name="description">
    <meta content="Accoutrements, Design, Manchester, Photography, Publishing, Screen Printing" name="keywords">
    <meta content="index,follow" name="robot">
    <meta content="© 2017 Accoutrements. All rights reserved." name="copyright">
    <meta content="Accoutrements" name="author">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
    <title>Accoutrements</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="accoutrements.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:400" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="corner_link about">
        <a href="/about">About</a>
    </div>
    <div class="corner_link shop">
        <a href="http://accoutrements.bigcartel.com">Shop</a>
    </div>
    <div class="corner_link catalogue">
        <a href="/catalogue">Catalogue</a>
    </div>
    <div class="corner_link instagram">
        <a href="http://instagram.com/accoutrements.studio">Instagram</a>
    </div>
    <div class="accoutrements">
        <a href="/colour"><svg class="logo" id="accoutrements" viewbox="0 0 800 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <title>Accoutrements</title>
        <path d="M32,160H24l-2,40H0L12,0H44L56,200H34ZM28,48l-4,88h8Z"></path>
        <path d="M494,0h30l4,100L532,0h30V200H540V88l-8,112h-8L516,88V200H494Z"></path>
        <path d="M650,0l8,112V0h20V200H652L644,74V200H622V0Z"></path>
        <polygon points="318 0 318 24 332 24 332 200 356 200 356 24 370 24 370 0 318 0"></polygon>
        <polygon points="686 0 686 24 700 24 700 200 724 200 724 24 738 24 738 0 686 0"></polygon>
        <polygon points="466 24 486 24 486 0 442 0 442 200 486 200 486 176 466 176 466 112 482 112 482 88 466 88 466 24"></polygon>
        <polygon points="594 24 614 24 614 0 570 0 570 200 614 200 614 176 594 176 594 112 610 112 610 88 594 88 594 24"></polygon>
        <path d="M118,90V28c0-8.13-1.94-14.87-6-20S101.87,0,92,0H88C78.13,0,72.05,2.87,68,8s-6,11.87-6,20V172c0,8.13,1.94,14.87,6,20s10.13,8,20,8h4c9.87,0,15.95-2.87,20-8s6-11.87,6-20V110H94v64a4,4,0,0,1-8,0V26a4,4,0,0,1,8,0V90Z"></path>
        <path d="M182,90V28c0-8.13-1.94-14.87-6-20s-10.13-8-20-8h-4c-9.87,0-15.95,2.87-20,8s-6,11.87-6,20V172c0,8.13,1.94,14.87,6,20s10.13,8,20,8h4c9.87,0,15.95-2.87,20-8s6-11.87,6-20V110H158v64a4,4,0,0,1-8,0V26a4,4,0,0,1,8,0V90Z"></path>
        <path d="M240,8c-4.05-5.13-10.13-8-20-8h-4c-9.87,0-15.95,2.87-20,8s-6,11.87-6,20V172c0,8.13,1.94,14.87,6,20s10.13,8,20,8h4c9.87,0,15.95-2.87,20-8s6-11.87,6-20V28C246,19.87,244.06,13.13,240,8ZM222,174a4,4,0,0,1-8,0V26a4,4,0,0,1,8,0Z"></path>
        <path d="M286,0V174a4,4,0,0,1-8,0V0H254V172c0,8.13,1.94,14.87,6,20s10.13,8,20,8h4c9.87,0,15.95-2.87,20-8s6-11.87,6-20V0Z"></path>
        <path d="M434,76V20c0-16-7.16-20-16-20H378V200h24V112h4a4,4,0,0,1,4,4v84h24V108c0-6-2-14-10-14C434,94,434,81.52,434,76Zm-24,8a4,4,0,0,1-4,4h-4V22h4a4,4,0,0,1,4,4Z"></path>
        <path d="M794,8c-4.05-5.13-10.13-8-20-8h-4c-9.87,0-15.95,2.87-20,8s-6,11.87-6,20V74c0,6.19.24,9.49,2,14s5.77,9.94,10,14l10,10c1.94,1.95,10,8,10,14v48a4,4,0,0,1-8,0V118H744v54c0,8.13,1.94,14.87,6,20s10.13,8,20,8h4c9.87,0,15.95-2.87,20-8s6-11.87,6-20V126c0-6.9-.06-11.76-2-16s-5.07-7.4-10-12c0,0-6.43-6.07-12-12-4.25-4.53-8-8.61-8-12V26a4,4,0,0,1,8,0V82h24V28C800,19.87,798.06,13.13,794,8Z"></path></svg></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Colour**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180">
    <link href="/favicon-32x32.png" rel="icon" sizes="32x32" type="image/png">
    <link href="/favicon-16x16.png" rel="icon" sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
    <link href="/manifest.json" rel="manifest">
    <meta content="#ffffff" name="theme-color">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="Accoutrements is a design studio established in 2016 by Jacob D'Rozario and Joseph Ng." name="description">
    <meta content="Accoutrements, Design, Manchester, Photography, Publishing, Screen Printing" name="keywords">
    <meta content="index,follow" name="robot">
    <meta content="© 2017 Accoutrements. All rights reserved." name="copyright">
    <meta content="Accoutrements" name="author">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
    <title>Accoutrements</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="accoutrements.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:400" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="corner_link about">
        <a href="/about">About</a>
    </div>
    <div class="corner_link shop">
        <a href="http://accoutrements.bigcartel.com">Shop</a>
    </div>
    <div class="corner_link catalogue">
        <a href="/catalogue">Catalogue</a>
    </div>
    <div class="corner_link instagram">
        <a href="http://instagram.com/accoutrements.studio">Instagram</a>
    </div>
    <div class="accoutrements">
        <svg class="logo" id="accoutrements" viewbox="0 0 800 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <title>Accoutrements</title>
        <path d="M32,160H24l-2,40H0L12,0H44L56,200H34ZM28,48l-4,88h8Z"></path>
        <path d="M494,0h30l4,100L532,0h30V200H540V88l-8,112h-8L516,88V200H494Z"></path>
        <path d="M650,0l8,112V0h20V200H652L644,74V200H622V0Z"></path>
        <polygon points="318 0 318 24 332 24 332 200 356 200 356 24 370 24 370 0 318 0"></polygon>
        <polygon points="686 0 686 24 700 24 700 200 724 200 724 24 738 24 738 0 686 0"></polygon>
        <polygon points="466 24 486 24 486 0 442 0 442 200 486 200 486 176 466 176 466 112 482 112 482 88 466 88 466 24"></polygon>
        <polygon points="594 24 614 24 614 0 570 0 570 200 614 200 614 176 594 176 594 112 610 112 610 88 594 88 594 24"></polygon>
        <path d="M118,90V28c0-8.13-1.94-14.87-6-20S101.87,0,92,0H88C78.13,0,72.05,2.87,68,8s-6,11.87-6,20V172c0,8.13,1.94,14.87,6,20s10.13,8,20,8h4c9.87,0,15.95-2.87,20-8s6-11.87,6-20V110H94v64a4,4,0,0,1-8,0V26a4,4,0,0,1,8,0V90Z"></path>
        <path d="M182,90V28c0-8.13-1.94-14.87-6-20s-10.13-8-20-8h-4c-9.87,0-15.95,2.87-20,8s-6,11.87-6,20V172c0,8.13,1.94,14.87,6,20s10.13,8,20,8h4c9.87,0,15.95-2.87,20-8s6-11.87,6-20V110H158v64a4,4,0,0,1-8,0V26a4,4,0,0,1,8,0V90Z"></path>
        <path d="M240,8c-4.05-5.13-10.13-8-20-8h-4c-9.87,0-15.95,2.87-20,8s-6,11.87-6,20V172c0,8.13,1.94,14.87,6,20s10.13,8,20,8h4c9.87,0,15.95-2.87,20-8s6-11.87,6-20V28C246,19.87,244.06,13.13,240,8ZM222,174a4,4,0,0,1-8,0V26a4,4,0,0,1,8,0Z"></path>
        <path d="M286,0V174a4,4,0,0,1-8,0V0H254V172c0,8.13,1.94,14.87,6,20s10.13,8,20,8h4c9.87,0,15.95-2.87,20-8s6-11.87,6-20V0Z"></path>
        <path d="M434,76V20c0-16-7.16-20-16-20H378V200h24V112h4a4,4,0,0,1,4,4v84h24V108c0-6-2-14-10-14C434,94,434,81.52,434,76Zm-24,8a4,4,0,0,1-4,4h-4V22h4a4,4,0,0,1,4,4Z"></path>
        <path d="M794,8c-4.05-5.13-10.13-8-20-8h-4c-9.87,0-15.95,2.87-20,8s-6,11.87-6,20V74c0,6.19.24,9.49,2,14s5.77,9.94,10,14l10,10c1.94,1.95,10,8,10,14v48a4,4,0,0,1-8,0V118H744v54c0,8.13,1.94,14.87,6,20s10.13,8,20,8h4c9.87,0,15.95-2.87,20-8s6-11.87,6-20V126c0-6.9-.06-11.76-2-16s-5.07-7.4-10-12c0,0-6.43-6.07-12-12-4.25-4.53-8-8.61-8-12V26a4,4,0,0,1,8,0V82h24V28C800,19.87,798.06,13.13,794,8Z"></path></svg> 
        <script>
                  var safeColors = ['00', '33', '66', '99', 'cc', 'ff'];
                  var rand = function() {
                  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
                  };
                  var randomColor = function() {
                  var r = safeColors[rand()];
                  var g = safeColors[rand()];
                  var b = safeColors[rand()];
                  return "#" + r + g + b;
                  };
                  var color_1 = randomColor();
                  var color_2 = randomColor();
                  $(document).ready(function() {
                  color_change();
                  $('#accoutrements').click(function() {
                      color_change();
                  });
                  });
                  function color_change() {
                  color_1 = randomColor();
                  color_2 = randomColor();
                  $('.corner_link a').css('color', color_1);
                  $('.accoutrements').css('fill', color_1);
                  $('body').css('background', color_2);
                  $('.corner_link a').hover(function(){ $(this).css('color',color_2).css('background-color',color_1); }, function(){ $(this).css('color',color_1).css('background-color','transparent'); });
                  }
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
   body {
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    line-height: 27px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #111;
    background-color: #fff;
   }

   .about {
    position: fixed;
    right: 40px;
    bottom: 40px;
   }

   .shop {
    position: fixed;
    right: 40px;
    top: 40px;
   }

   .catalogue {
    position: fixed;
    left: 40px;
    top: 40px;
   }

   .instagram {
    position: fixed;
    left: 40px;
    bottom: 40px;
   }

   a img {
     text-decoration: none;
     border:none;
     border-bottom-style: none;
   }

   a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #111;
   }

   a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #111;
   }

   a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
   }

   a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #111;
   }

   .accoutrements {
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: 50vh;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    cursor: pointer;
   }

   svg.logo {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 80%;
    left: 10%;
   }

   svg.logo:emptyc {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   }

   @media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    svg.logo {
        max-width: 800px;
        position: inherit;
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
    }
   }

   .text {
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: 50vh;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix the black box remove the following code in your css

```
   a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
   }
```

Alignment issue looks fine to me on all devices. Tested.

To fix the coloring issue, no need to have separate pages. You can execute your script once the page loads. Suppose you want to color page after 5 seconds so your code will look like:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            // Your color logic
        }, 5000);
    });
```

So put this script in your index page only:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
                setTimeout(function(){
var safeColors = ['00', '33', '66', '99', 'cc', 'ff'];
                  var rand = function() {
                  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
                  };
                  var randomColor = function() {
                  var r = safeColors[rand()];
                  var g = safeColors[rand()];
                  var b = safeColors[rand()];
                  return "#" + r + g + b;
                  };
                  var color_1 = randomColor();
                  var color_2 = randomColor();
                  $(document).ready(function() {
                  color_change();
                  $('#accoutrements').click(function() {
                      color_change();
                  });
                  });
                  function color_change() {
                  color_1 = randomColor();
                  color_2 = randomColor();
                  $('.corner_link a').css('color', color_1);
                  $('.accoutrements').css('fill', color_1);
                  $('body').css('background', color_2);
                  $('.corner_link a').hover(function(){ $(this).css('color',color_2).css('background-color',color_1); }, function(){ $(this).css('color',color_1).css('background-color','transparent'); });
                  }
                }, 5000);
            });
```

Comment: I've solved the on-click function of the Javascript by adding: `$(document).click(function(){`

This has also fixed the hover effect on the svg as it is no longer an active link. It's still not aligning correctly on an iPhone/iPad for me though. I'm getting a vertical mis-alignment. Could this be an iOS Safari issue? Which browser/mobile device are you using? Thanks.

Comment: Could be an iOS issue. I tested on browser's mobile emulator.

Comment: Yep it looks fine on the Chrome responsive mode but not on an actual mobile device. This is how it looks on iOS Safari — https://i.imgur.com/GnRSEmn.png